# MBP mid 14 won't boot post kernel panic? Frozen on Apple logo

Tags: hard-drive, startup

*Suspect:* **Macbook Pro Mid 2014 13" Retina on macOS High Sierra**

*Symptoms:* suddenly frozen under normal usage (Chrome browsing), similar to a kernel panic, Shut down by holding the power button. **Not capable to boot since**.

*Charge*: **hard drive failure?**

Here is some evidence I was capable to collect:

- system won't start, freezes on Apple logo w/ loading bar
- Recovery partition Disk Utility tool cannot fix the hard drive (errors with a message that drive cannot be unmounted/mounted)
- The diagnostic boot mode (cmd+D) crashes after language selection (frozen and nothing happens)
- Verbose mode (cmd+V) leaves the computer with constantly scrolling unreadable message about "spaceman_free..." (pictured below)
  [image: display photo under Verbose mode boot]

In all the above cases, the Macbook is unresponsive and has to be shut down by holding the power button.

Does anyone have a similar issue or have any idea how to proceed with the current situation?

*Update I (09/26/19):*

- I **haven't installed** any software before the event;
- My account was the **only one** and w/ **administrator** privileges;
- **SIP is enabled** (at least if it is by default);
- after some thought, I have recalled that I had **at least one pending update** that **couldn't be finished due to some issue**.
- the attempt of **OS reinstallation failed** due to the fact that the **hard drive cannot be unmounted**.

I am afraid that lot of this information is noise over signal but I cannot tell at this point what is more helpful for someone experienced.

I will update this post with anything new I manage to learn.

Comment: It really does sound like a hard drive failure. Have you got access to another Mac? If so, what model(s)?

Comment: I am curious, did you by any chance have System Integrity Protection (SIP) disabled?

Comment: If SIP is enable by default then it is enabled. And yes, my account was **the only one** and with **administrator** privileges. I'm trying to get access to MPB 17" late 2011 (MacBookPro8,3) to try boot from the hard drive using target disk mode.

As you might expect the attempt of reinstalling OS failed since one of the steps is the **hard drive unmounting, which cannot be performed**.

Before the event, I **haven't installed any software** but I am afraid I had at least one pending update that now I recall couldn't be finished due to some issue